# What's the relation between degeneracy and $\pi$-flux

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics

### Ring with magnetic flux

Assuming a particle locates in a ring which circle a magnetic flux,

[image]

the Hamiltonian is:
$$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2 m}(\hat{p}-A)^{2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2 m}\left(-i \partial_{\phi}-A\right)^{2}$$
and the energy is:
[image]
there exists ground state degeneracy for $\pi$ flux.

### Square lattice with magnetic flux

Assuming a particle in square lattice with a magnetic flux:
$$\begin{array}{l}H=-t \sum_{i, j} c_{i}^{\dagger} c_{j}+h . c \rightarrow-t_{1} e^{\frac{i e}{\hbar} A_{i, j}} \sum_{i, j} c_{i}^{\dagger} c_{j}+h . c \\ =-t \sum_{i, j} c_{(i, j)}^{\dagger} c_{(i+1, j)}-\mathrm{t} e^{-\frac{i e}{\hbar} i \Phi} \sum_{i, j} c_{(i, j)}^{\dagger} c_{(i, j+1)}+h . c\end{array}$$

and setting the gauge as the following picture,

[image]

we can also find ground state degeneracy for $\pi$ flux ($N_e=1$):
[image]
which indicates the two-fold ground state degeneracy.

### Question

I am confused that the relation between degeneracy and $\pi$-flux, i.e. symmetry breaking.